# NetStream.appendBytes

Tags: flash, actionscript, video-streaming, arrays, flash-media-server

I have a netConnection connected to a Flash Media Server. I am trying to use the new appendBytes function from Flash Player 10.1 to stream a local FLV file to FMS. I'm having issues however... Documentation I get online

```
function playFile(data:ByteArray):void
{
// data is bytearray data from an already loaded FileReference object
    netStream.play(null);
    netStream.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN);
    netStream.appendBytes(data);
}
```

However, I'm getting an error with the appendBytesAction and appendBytes. The error is: Error #2004: One of the parameters is invalid....

```
TypeError: Error #2004: One of the parameters is invalid.
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `appendBytes` successfully when your stream's `NetConnection` is connected to anything else than "null". From the documentation of `appendBytes` method at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#appendBytes%28%29:

> Passes a `ByteArray` into a `NetStream` for playout. Call this method on a `NetStream` in "Data Generation Mode". To put a `NetStream` into Data Generation Mode, call `NetStream.play(null)` on a `NetStream` created on a `NetConnection` connected to null. Calling `appendBytes()` on a `NetStream` that isn't in Data Generation Mode is an error and raises an exception.

This almost certainly implies that what Adobe calls "Data Generation Mode" will not be available on a connection object connected to say, a Flash Media Server instance.

Comment: Yes, just found read that this morning. Sort of lame... Don't understand why they wouldn't allow appendBytes on a NetStream out of data generation mode.. Would save people from having to use ManyCam and Soundflower when trying to stream a video file online.

Comment: Had the same issue, absolutely shocking this isn't allowed. As others hinted at, it's likely an arbitrary limitation put in place for business reasons :(